Google Analytics 4 Are the reports per user only?
I'm using a simple Tag in google tag manager as you can see below

The major_button_click is connected with the button in homepage. The tag works fine, the event is firing as intended. The question is, if i press a second the button, the event will fire again but the event wont be registered in the real time reports. If i open another window in the browser in incognito mode, the event will be registered as intended.
Are the events related per user and not by how many time a user clicks ?
